# Unhandled Exception handling in C#

Tags: c#, exception, unhandled-exception

I am trying to understand how a C# program handles an unhandled Exception.

I am doing my testing in a windows forms project, If the answer is different in other project types, please let me know.

I am running the program from the .exe file and not from the visual studio debugger.

Code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //timer1.Interval = 10000
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new Exception(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " This is an exception");
    }
}
static class Program
{

    static Form1 newForm;

    static void Main()
    {
        Thread FormThread = new Thread(NewForm);
        FormThread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        //throw new Exception(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " This is an exception");
    }

    static void NewForm()
    {
        newForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(newForm);
    }
}
```

My question is what will be the windows response for an unhandled Exception in a C# program?

in the above example:

If the exception is thrown from the timer1_Tick function (by deleting the comment prefix) I am getting the following message:
[image: timer1_Tick Exception]

If the exception is thrown from the Main function (by deleting the comment prefix) I am getting the following message:
[image: Main Exception]

why I am getting 2 different messages and how the windows/program "choose" which message to pop.

Thank you.

Comment: Your running both of these tests from a compiled `.exe`?

Comment: Yes, I am running the file Test-Windows Forms.exe. not from visual studio.

Comment: The first one is a "continuable" exception, since it just terminates the forked thread, the main thread continues to run. The second one is an exception on the main thread, which cannot be terminated without terminating the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a WinForms application, event handlers are invoked by the `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`. When an event handler throws an unhandled exception, the context handles it by displaying the first error dialog. At that point the synchronization context (which is simply a message pump) is still running and it could still proceed handling other events, so you are given a choice.

The `Main` method, in contrast, is invoked by the operating system itself, to start the application. If there is an unhandled exception there, WIndows has no option but to terminate the application, and it shows the second dialog to inform you of this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am little weak in the SynchronizationContext topic so sorry if this questions is "stupid" . if I understand you correctly, an unhandled exception thrown by a UI Thread (a Thread that control a WinForms application) will be caught by the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and not result in the program termination? (only if the user Selected "quit"). What will happen if another thread (not the main thread, a new Thread using Thread.Start) will throw an unhandled exception?

Comment: See [Exceptions in managed threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/exceptions-in-managed-threads)